# Parse Cloud Code DOM manipulation equivalent

Tags: dom, parse-platform, meta-tags, meta, parse-cloud-code

Given a url, I need to extract some `meta` content. For instance, say I need to get the content of the tag `<meta property="og:site_name" ... content="some name"/>` so that I can persist it inside a ParseObject before I save. So the general structure of my cloud code would look like

```
Parse.Cloud.beforeSave(“Food”,function(request,response){
    if(!request.user || !request.user.authenticated()){
        response.error("Need an authenticated user");
    }else if(!request.params.link || request.params.link==""){
            esponse.error("Need a link");
    }else{
        Parse.Cloud.httpRequest({
            url:link,
            success:function(httpResponse){
              //TODO I need to extract meta content here: for site_name
            },
            error:function(httpResponse){
                response.error("request failed with response code "+httpResponse.status);
            }
        });
    }
});
```

Here is my question: **What do I do with `httpResponse` in order to extract the data?**

For instance if I had a DOM object, I could simply do

```
function getMetaContent() { 
   var metas = document.getElementsByTagName('meta'); 

   for (i=0; i<metas.length; i++) { 
      if (metas[i].getAttribute("property") == “og:site_name”) { 
         var content= metas[i].getAttribute("content");
        … 
      } 
   } 

    return "";
}
```

Thanks for any help, and if the question is too simple it's because I am a backend guy needing to code javascript for Parse Cloud Code.